# How do I avoid the "self.x = x; self.y = y; self.z = z" pattern in __init__?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, namedtuple, python-attrs

I see patterns like

```
def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    ...
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
    ...
```

quite frequently, often with a lot more parameters. Is there a good way to avoid this type of tedious repetitiveness? Should the class inherit from `namedtuple` instead?

Comment: Not all receptiveness is bad. Keep in mind that Python's class model doesn't include explicit definition of instance attributes, so these assignments are the self-documenting equivalents.

Comment: @chepner: Well, doesn't _require_ explicit definition. You can use [`__slots__` for the purpose though](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots); it's mildly unpythonic (more verbose to get memory savings), but I like it largely to avoid the risk of auto-vivifying a whole new attribute if I typo the name.

Comment: Any good editor will have templates. You type `ini <shortcut> x, y, z): <shortcut>` and you are done.

Comment: Namedtuples are awesome, _if_ you want an immutable value object. If you want a regular, mutable class, you can't use them.

Comment: "Don't" is a good option, any option available will kill the method signature (and thus potentially the whole interface). Besides, if your classes have a unbearable amount of fields to initialize, you might want to consider splitting them.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich a class derived from `namedtuple` can have mutable attributes (in addition to the immutable inherited ones)

Comment: Remember that this pattern also allows you to set defaults for x/y/z.  Alternatives don't.  And besides, it's only tedious if it's a substantial part of the work.  I've been in this industry for 20 years, and I've never yet seen a constructor where copying parameters was a significant portion of the whole file!

Comment: Rather than this being a common pattern, init methods often only **start** with this pattern. As you keep working with it, you will almost certainly need to do some additional logic with at least some args, and therefore with an auto-setting approach you will need to now do processing of self.<name> properties you've just set, so that overall init code looks more complicated than the alternative.

Comment: Removed the decorators tag; it's unclear what OP had in mind, and the mere fact that dataclasses are implemented with a decorator does not make decorators relevant here (otherwise, we'd tag *every* question about dataclasses with decorators as well). It makes sense to add the dataclasses tag after-the-fact because it helps people (who already know the answer) find this canonical duplicate; but they would not expect the decorators tag so it is not useful.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Edit:
If you have python 3.7+ just use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

A decorator solution that keeps the signature:

```
import decorator
import inspect
import sys


@decorator.decorator
def simple_init(func, self, *args, **kws):
    """
    @simple_init
    def __init__(self,a,b,...,z)
        dosomething()

    behaves like

    def __init__(self,a,b,...,z)
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        ...
        self.z = z
        dosomething()
    """

    #init_argumentnames_without_self = ['a','b',...,'z']
    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        init_argumentnames_without_self = inspect.getargspec(func).args[1:]
    else:
        init_argumentnames_without_self = tuple(inspect.signature(func).parameters.keys())[1:]

    positional_values = args
    keyword_values_in_correct_order = tuple(kws[key] for key in init_argumentnames_without_self if key in kws)
    attribute_values = positional_values + keyword_values_in_correct_order

    for attribute_name,attribute_value in zip(init_argumentnames_without_self,attribute_values):
        setattr(self,attribute_name,attribute_value)

    # call the original __init__
    func(self, *args, **kws)


class Test():
    @simple_init
    def __init__(self,a,b,c,d=4):
        print(self.a,self.b,self.c,self.d)

#prints 1 3 2 4
t = Test(1,c=2,b=3)
#keeps signature
#prints ['self', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    print(inspect.getargspec(Test.__init__).args)
else:
    print(inspect.signature(Test.__init__))
```

Comment: nice answer, but won't work with python2.7: no `signature`

Comment: Shouldn't `simple_init`, as a decorator, **return** the decorated function instead of calling it?

Comment: @alexis the "decorator.decorator" decorator automatically wraps the function

Comment: I'm quite torn about whether to love this or hate it. I do appreciate preserving the signature.

Comment: "... Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex. ..." -Zen of Python

Comment: -1 Quite frankly this is horrible. I have no idea what this code is doing at a glance, and it's literally ten times the amount of code. Being clever feels cool and all, but this is a misuse of your obvious cleverness.

Comment: Note that `decorator` [is third-party](https://pypi.org/project/decorator/). @IanNewson this is basically implementing dataclasses for earlier versions of Python, but reading names from `__init__` and modifying it, rather than reading names from class attributes and generating `__init__` from scratch. The `simple_init` decorator only needs to be written once, for arbitrarily many classes that want this kind of initialization.

Answer (score 108):

**Disclaimer:** It seems that several people are concerned about presenting this solution, so I will provide a very clear disclaimer. You should not use this solution. I only provide it as information, so you know that the language is capable of this. The rest of the answer is just showing language capabilities, not endorsing using them in this way.

---

There isn't really anything wrong with explicitly copying parameters into attributes. If you have too many parameters in the ctor, it is sometimes considered a code smell and maybe you should group these params into a fewer objects. Other times, it is necessary and there is nothing wrong with it. **Anyway, doing it explicitly is the way to go.**

However, since you are asking HOW it can be done (and not whether it should be done), then one solution is this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in kwargs:
          setattr(self, key, kwargs[key])

a = A(l=1, d=2)
a.l # will return 1
a.d # will return 2
```

Comment: good answer +1 ... although `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)` might be marginally more pythonic

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there is no record of what arguments `A.__init__` actually expects, and no error checking for mistyped argument names.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Updating the instance dictionary blindly with `kwargs` leaves you open to the equivalent of an SQL injection attack. If your object has a method named `my_method` and you pass an argument named `my_method` to the constructor, then `update()` the dictionary, you just overwrote the method.

Comment: As others said, the suggestion is really poor programming style. It hides crucial information. You can show it, but you should explicitely discourage the OP from using it.

Comment: I believe the first two paragraph discourage from using the method. The user asked for how something is done and I think he/she received enough feedback that he/she shouldn't do that. It should still be useful for him/her to learn about this approach, even if he/she won't use it.

Comment: I also bolded the sentence that clearly states that the author of the question should do this explicitly.

Comment: You are right, sorry. I had the suspicion that the user might not realize how bad it would be.

Comment: @Pedro Is there any semantic difference between gruzczy's and JoranBeasley's syntax?

Comment: @gerrit The only thing I can think of (I'm typing on my phone so I can't test) is that `setattr()` might trigger setter logic if you have a `@property.setter` in your object, whereas the dictionary update won't. Other than that, they are equivalent.

Comment: holy crap ... I should have put more effort into my answer ... no idea it would get 42 upvotes ...

Comment: What's wrong with it is that it is extra lines of code without improving readability. If that's pythonic then okay, but it doesn't mean there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I added one more disclaimer that this is only to show capabilities of the language and it shouldn't be used in real projects

Answer (score 29):

Explicit is better than implicit ...
so sure, you could make it more concise:

```
def __init__(self,a,b,c):
    for k,v in locals().items():
        if k != "self":
             setattr(self,k,v)
```

The better question is: should you?

... that said if you want a named tuple I would recommend using a namedtuple (remember tuples have certain conditions attached to them) ... perhaps you want an OrderedDict or even just a dict ...

Comment: Then the object will need cyclic garbage collection since it has itself as an attribute

Comment: @bernie (or is it bemie?), sometimes ke  r ning is hard

Comment: For slightly more efficient tests, `if k != "self":` could be changed to `if v is not self:`, cheap identity test, rather than string comparison. I suppose technically `__init__` could be called a second time after construction and passed `self` as a subsequent argument, but I really don't want to think what sort of monster would do that. :-)

Comment: That could be made into a function which takes the return value of `locals`: `set_fields_from_locals(locals())`. Then it's no longer than the more magical decorator based solutions.

Answer (score 29):

As others have mentioned, the repetition isn't bad, but in some cases a namedtuple can be a great fit for this type of issue. This avoids using locals() or kwargs, which are usually a bad idea.

```
from collections import namedtuple
# declare a new object type with three properties; x y z
# the first arg of namedtuple is a typename
# the second arg is comma-separated or space-separated property names
XYZ = namedtuple("XYZ", "x, y, z")

# create an object of type XYZ. properties are in order
abc = XYZ("one", "two", 3)
print abc.x
print abc.y
print abc.z
```

I've found limited use for it, but you can inherit a namedtuple as with any other object (example continued):

```
class MySuperXYZ(XYZ):
    """ I add a helper function which returns the original properties """
    def properties(self):
        return self.x, self.y, self.z

abc2 = MySuperXYZ(4, "five", "six")
print abc2.x
print abc2.y
print abc2.z
print abc2.properties()
```

Comment: These *are* tuples, so your `properties` method can be written as just `return tuple(self)`, which is more maintainable if in future more fields are added to the namedtuple definition.

Comment: Also, your namedtuple declaration string does not require commas between the fieldnames, `XYZ = namedtuple("XYZ", "x y z")` works just as well.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcGuire. I was trying to think of a really simple add-on to show the inheritance and kind of spaced on that. You're 100% right and it's a great shorthand with other inherited objects, too! I do mention the field names can be comma or space separated -- I prefer CSV from habit

Comment: I often use `namedtuple`s for this exact purpose, especially in mathematical code where a function might be highly parametrised and have a bunch of coefficients that only make sense together.

Comment: The problem with `namedtuple` is that they are read-only. You can not do `abc.x += 1` or anything like that.

Comment: @hamstergene: it's solely a good thing. ;) The only downside is that you have to write your own `update` methods (that return a fresh copy with a particular field updated)

Answer (score 21):

To expand on `gruszczy`s answer, I have used a pattern like:

```
class X:
    x = None
    y = None
    z = None
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for (k, v) in kwargs.items():
            if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)
            else:
                raise TypeError('Unknown keyword argument: {:s}'.format(k))
```

I like this method because it:

- avoids repetition
- is resistant against typos when constructing an object
- works well with subclassing (can just `super().__init(...)`)
- allows for documentation of the attributes on a class-level (where they belong) rather than in `X.__init__`

Prior to Python 3.6, this gives no control over the order in which the attributes are set, which could be a problem if some attributes are properties with setters that access other attributes.

It could probably be improved upon a bit, but I'm the only user of my own code so I am not worried about any form of input sanitation.  Perhaps an `AttributeError` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

You could also do:

```
locs = locals()
for arg in inspect.getargspec(self.__init__)[0][1:]:
    setattr(self, arg, locs[arg])
```

Of course, you would have to import the `inspect` module.

Answer (score 8):

This is a solution without any additional imports.

### Helper function

A small helper function makes it more convenient and re-usable:

```
def auto_init(local_name_space):
    """Set instance attributes from arguments.
    """
    self = local_name_space.pop('self')
    for name, value in local_name_space.items():
        setattr(self, name, value)
```

### Application

You need to call it with `locals()`:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        auto_init(locals())
```

### Test

```
a = A(1, 2, 3)
print(a.__dict__)
```

Output:

```
{'y': 2, 'z': 3, 'x': 1}
```

### Without changing `locals()`

If you don't like to change `locals()` use this version:

```
def auto_init(local_name_space):
    """Set instance attributes from arguments.
    """
    for name, value in local_name_space.items():
        if name != 'self': 
            setattr(local_name_space['self'], name, value)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals `locals()` should not be modified (it may affect the interpreter, in your case, removing `self` from the calling function's scope)

Comment: @MaxB From the docs you cite: *... changes may **not** affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.* `self` is still available in `__init__` .

Comment: Right, the reader expects it to affect the local variables, but it may or may **not**, depending on a number of circumstances. The point is that it's UB.

Comment: Quote: "The contents of this dictionary should not be modified"

Comment: @MaxB I added a version that does not change locals().

Answer (score 8):

### Python 3.7 onwards

In Python 3.7, you may (ab)use the [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) decorator, available from the `dataclasses` module.  From the documentation:

> This module provides a decorator and functions for automatically adding generated special methods such as `__init__()` and `__repr__()` to user-defined classes. It was originally described in PEP 557.
>
> The member variables to use in these generated methods are defined using PEP 526 type annotations. For example this code:
>
> ```
> @dataclass
> class InventoryItem:
>     '''Class for keeping track of an item in inventory.'''
>     name: str
>     unit_price: float
>     quantity_on_hand: int = 0
>
>     def total_cost(self) -> float:
>         return self.unit_price * self.quantity_on_hand
> ```
>
> Will add, among other things, a `__init__()` that looks like:
>
> ```
> def __init__(self, name: str, unit_price: float, quantity_on_hand: int=0):
>       self.name = name
>       self.unit_price = unit_price
>       self.quantity_on_hand = quantity_on_hand
> ```
>
> Note that this method is automatically added to the class: it is not directly specified in the InventoryItem definition shown above.

If your class is large and complex, it *may* be inappropriate to use a `dataclass`.  I'm writing this on the day of release of Python 3.7.0, so usage patterns are not yet well established.

Comment: Since 3.6 and below are now end-of-life, this should be the preferred answer.

Answer (score 7):

An interesting library that handles this (and avoids a lot of other boilerplate) is [attrs](https://attrs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Your example, for instance, could be reduced to this (assume the class is called `MyClass`):

```
import attr

@attr.s
class MyClass:
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()
    z = attr.ib()
```

You don't even need an `__init__` method anymore, unless it does other stuff as well. Here's [a nice introduction by Glyph Lefkowitz](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/attrs.html).

Comment: To what degree is the functionaly of `attr` made redundant by [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses)?

Comment: @gerrit This is discussed in the [documentation of the attrs package](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/why.html#data-classes). Tbh, the differences don't seem that large anymore.

Answer (score 5):

My 0.02$. It is very close to Joran Beasley answer, but more elegant:

```
def __init__(self, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    vars(self).update((k, v) for k, v in locals().items() if v is not self)
```

Additionally, Mike Müller's answer (the best one to my taste) can be reduced with this technique:

```
def auto_init(ns):
    self = ns.pop('self')
    vars(self).update(ns)
```

And the just call `auto_init(locals())` from your `__init__`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals `locals()` should not be modified (undefined behavior)